# python relative import error

Tags: python, linux

this is my project structure

```
Project/
      docs/
      scripts/
      project-2.5/
          bin/
             program.py
             __init__.py
          config/
             config.ini
          tests/
          src/
             main_program.py
             __init__.py
      __init__.py
```

the user is supposed to execute program.py and it would pass the options to main_program.py

```
eg. bin/># python program.py -c ../config/config.ini
```

**program.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import optparse
from ..src.main_program import main_function

def main():
    parser = optparse.OptionParser()
    parser.add_option('-c', '--config',
                      dest="config_file",
                      default='config.ini'
                        )
    options, remainder = parser.parse_args()
    main_function(options)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**main_program.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env
import sys

def main_function(options):
    blah blah blah
    ......
    ...
    ..
    .
```

however I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./program.py", line 6, in <module>
    from ..src.main_program import main_function
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

Answer (score 1):

The `__init__.py` has the wrong name in your `src` folder. It's missing the `.` in the filename.

Also, your `Project/project-2.5/` folder does not have a `__init__.py` either. If you fix those issues, it should work fine.

Comment: it was a typo in the question(fixed), also the Project/project-2.5/ has a  __init__.py, I still get the same error

Comment: That __init__ in Project/project-2.5 is not in your project structure (it's one level higher).